# Using call() with namespace address (:: or :::)

Tags: r

I am having trouble using the `call()` function together with the namespace address operators `::` and `:::`. Simply adding it to the function name as supplied for `call()` produces an error when the call is evaluated, as this silly example shows:

```
> call("base::print", "Hi there")
`base::print`("Hi there")
> eval(call("base::print", "Hi there"))
Error in `base::print`("Hi there") : 
 could not find function "base::print"
```

For some reason, `call()` adds backticks around the function name (probably because it contains non-standard characters), which seems to mess up everything.  Here is what happens when the "address" is omitted:

```
> call("print", "Hi there")
print("Hi there")
> eval(call("print", "Hi there"))
[1] "Hi there"
```

I will very much appreciate any suggestions for how to solve this issue. Note however that I need to produce the code with `call()`, as I am autogenerating code for rmarkdown code chunks, and I need to be able to specify the namespace, because I am using an unexported function from my package which I would really like to stay unexported.

Thanks for reading!

---

Update: I neglected to mention another property of the solution I am looking for (which I became aware of by reading Stéphane Laurent's otherwise great answer below): I am looking for a solution where the function definition is not copied into the call, which I believe rules out solutions using `get()`. As an example of what I am trying to avoid, let's say we want to call `qplot()` from `ggplot2`. If we use e.g. `getFromNamespace()` the call will look like this (with the middle part of the output omitted for making it easier to read):

```
> as.call(list(getFromNamespace("qplot", "ggplot2"), 1:10))

  (function (x, y = NULL, ..., data, facets = NULL, margins = FALSE, 
  geom = "auto", xlim = c(NA, NA), ylim = c(NA, NA), log = "", 
  main = NULL, xlab = deparse(substitute(x)), ylab = deparse(substitute(y)), 
asp = NA, stat = NULL, position = NULL) 
{
  if (!missing(stat)) 
      warning("`stat` is deprecated", call. = FALSE)
  if (!missing(position)) 
      warning("`position` is deprecated", call. = FALSE)
  if (!is.character(geom)) 
      stop("`geom` must be a character vector", call. = FALSE)
  argnames <- names(as.list(match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)[-1]))
  arguments <- as.list(match.call()[-1])
  env <- parent.frame()

#### A lot more code defining the function (omitted)#####

  if (!missing(xlim)) 
      p <- p + xlim(xlim)
  if (!missing(ylim)) 
      p <- p + ylim(ylim)
  p
})(1:10)
```

The same thing happens if we instead use `as.call(list(ggplot2::qplot, 1:10))`.

What I am looking for is something that produces the call `ggplot2::qplot(1:10)`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe

```
> eval(as.call(list(getFromNamespace("print", "base"), "Hi there")))
[1] "Hi there"
```

Comment: While it's obvious to most experienced R users why this solution works, it might be nice to include a brief description of what's going on for the less experienced users to learn from.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know the `getFromNamespace()`. This works very well, but the call copies in the function definition. Do you know if this can be avoided? In my set-up, this copying will mean a lot of extra lines of code, as I will sometimes need to call  the unexported function e.g. 100 times in the same rmarkdown document.

Comment: @AHP Not sure to understand. In fact you can also do `eval(as.call(list(base::print, "Hi there")))`.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Sorry, I realize my comment was not so clear. I have tried explaining it in an update to the question - I hope this makes it more clear.