# building call()s prgramatically

Tags: r, expression, call

I want to construct function calls like this:

```r
my_simplecode <- "mtcars"
call("str", as.name(my_simplecode))
#> str(mtcars)
```

The problem is that `as.name()` introduces backticks when some symbols such as parentheses or brackets are in the code:

```r
my_code <- "mtcars[, 1:2]"
call("str", as.name(my_code))
#> str(`mtcars[, 1:2]`)
```

And this call cannot be evaluated.
I need to produce the call for `str(mtcars[, 1:2])`, but I cannot get rid of the quotes. Tried all combinations of quote(), enquote(), parse(), deparse(), expression(), et al. without success.

Note that `my_code` can be *anything*. A variable name, or more generally any expression, including function calls, pipes, whatever.

This is similar to [Using call() with namespace address (:: or :::)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46975292/using-call-with-namespace-address-or), but there the issue was in the function name.

Thanks in advance for any insights.

Comment: `my_code` isn't a name. It's a function call. You need to use `parse`. But that brings to mind the famous quote from the fortunes package: If `parse` is the answer, you are asking the wrong question.

Comment: Thank you Roland, but parse does not work either, since if I call("str", parse(text = my_code)), what I get is: str(expression(mtcars[, 1:2])).
Moreover, my_code can be anything, including a name as in my first example.

Comment: You need to explain in more detail what you want to do and why. You must parse the character string. The question is now what to do next but you haven't specified the goal sufficiently.

Comment: I want to produce a call programatically, where the function to be called and the arguments are stored in text strings. The goal is to return such a call as the outcome of a function, as if the call was written manually. For example, if `fun = "str"` and `text = "mtcars[]"` I want a function of `fun` and `text` that returns exactly the call for `str(mtcars[])`.

Comment: Yes, well, that doesn't sound like something you should do. At least, you haven't given a reason for wanting this. And if you had a good reason I would advise you to not pass character strings but expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not utterly elegant, but this works:

```r
my_code <- "mtcars[, 1:2]"
my_lang <- eval(parse(text = paste0("quote(", my_code, ")")))
call("str", my_lang)
#> str(mtcars[, 1:2])
```

Comment: I don't have better, we can define `as.language <- function(x) eval(parse(text = paste0("quote(", x, ")")))` for these situations

Answer (score 0):

I'm not as adept at the `quote` / `enquote` functions, but it might be easy enough to just write a little function for what you're trying to send into `call`, in this case getting the structure of just certain columns.

For example, I wrote this function:

`str_limited <- function(x, rows, cols) str(x[rows, cols])`

which you can call with the numbers of the rows and/or columns you want to subset, then used that as the function going into `call`, with the argument `cols = 1:2`:

`call("str_limited", as.name("mtcars"), cols = 1:2)`.

Testing the result of that with `eval` gave:

`'data.frame':   32 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ mpg: num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
 $ cyl: num  6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...`

which, if I understand correctly, is the output you'd be looking for upon evaluation.

My solution is generally when in doubt, write a function!

Comment: Thank you Camille. However, but this was only a minimal example. I was not looking for this particular functionality. my_code can be anything, and in fact it comes from a function argument, since this is indeed to be used within a function.